# Java runtime illegastateexception. specified child has already a parent

Tags: android, android-view

I am trying to play a video from the gallery. On button click it should start playing video in the videoView. But i get exception that spcified child already has parent. Following is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button bt= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final String filename = "/sdcard/myvideo.mp4";  
    Log.e("Video Error", "Problem Below");
     final VideoView videoView1 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        Log.e("Video Error", "Problem Above");
     setContentView(videoView1);
     videoView1.setVideoPath(filename);
    // videoView1.setMediaController(MainActivity.this);
     videoView1.requestFocus();
     bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              //String fileName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sample;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hey Baby", 5000);
              //videoView1.start();
              //Exit after saved
             // finish();

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

when i try to initialize my VideoView it gives the following exception:

```
:12:11.838: E/AndroidRuntime(1124): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 19:12:11.838: E/AndroidRuntime(1124): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start      activity ComponentInfo{com.et.getimages/com.et.getimages.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

please help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it'd because you're calling `setContentView()` twice. The first time creates the VideoView and then when `setContentView(videoView1);`

Without the full stacktrace it's impossible to tell however.

p.s. you'll want to add `show()` to your toast to make it display

Answer (score 0):

You set content view in this statement:

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

then you take from view defined in `layout/activity_main.xml` another view:

`(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);`

which is actaually  child of `layout/activity_main.xml`

and then you again try to set content view:

`setContentView(videoView1);`

but `videoView1` already has parent because it is part of `layout/activity_main.xml` so you cannot use this view in `setContentView()` as this method is setting up root for view given in parameter.